# Save Imacros as text file from Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, logging, google-chrome-extension, imacros

I have a task where I need to log all the user actions done in Chrome browser. Like a person typing anything in search box, clicking a page,etc. I need to save this as a log and read from that for further steps.

I am able to record the actions using Imacros in chrome. But when i try to save it as file it gives the following error. Can anyone please help?

**> Please install file support for iMacros to save macro as a file**

Comment: Make sure that you have downloaded the latest version [iMacros_for_Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp?hl=en) - this version fixes the Chrome V35 issues. You may also check the [`SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=*`](http://wiki.imacros.net/SAVEAS) which save extracted text to default file ("extract.csv" in iMacros "Downloads" folder).